# How to fetch Laravel cookie in an SPA if page only loads once

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cookies, laravel-8, vuejs3

I'm running a Vue3 SPA on a Laravel 8 backend.
I'm setting a cookie via middleware for unauthenticated users.
I can see the cookie and its value in Chrome's dev tools Sotrage > Cookies.
But I can't read its value inside of the Vue app, probably since it was set after the initial page load that created the Vue SPA.

Any idea how I can access that cookie?

Comment: @tony19 thanks you figured it out. Turns out Laravel ships with a HTTP only cookie setting.

Answer (score 1):

As determined from comments, you have HTTP-only cookies enabled, which prevents client-side JavaScript access to the cookies.

HTTP-only cookies are [intended for security purposes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies), but you can disable this with [`session-set-cookie-params`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php):

```php
<?php
  $options = array("httponly" => false);
  session_set_cookie_params($options);
  session_start();
?>
```

Or in [`laravel/config/session.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/d3efbaa/config/session.php#L184):

```php
<?php
  //...
  return [
    'http_only' => false
  ]
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set false HTTP-only the it when creating a cookie

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('token','token_here',525600,null,null,false,false));
}
```